# How to add to list my own items in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, list, listbox, pysimplegui

Is there any way to add a new item to the list in PySimpleGUI?
I've searched up the Google and found nothing useful.

Comment: You can call `help(list)` or `help(list.insert)` to get information how to add to list your own items, maybe more information required if it is not for list in you question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.